# Is it possible to pass args in bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post?

Tags: python

Like the obj argument I want to send more arguments to the function. It is not working right-now.

Thanks in advance

````
import bpy

def new_(scene,obj):
    obj.location.x = scene.frame_current
handler = bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post
for l in [l for l in handler]:
    handler.remove(l)
handler.append(new_(bpy.context.scene,bpy.context.object))
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bpy


def my_handler(string, object):
    
    def handler(scene):
        
        object.data.body = string + ":" + str(scene.frame_current)
        
    
    return handler
    
object = bpy.context.object


bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler("frame is", object))
```

You can test my little script with a text object selected.

The handler always expects scene as first argument, you cannot change that.
But you can return a function with scene as first argument inside your own handler function and use the parameter you gave them.

[image]

Comment: That's really helpful. Thanks